# Different types in sum function

Tags: haskell, types, sum, foldable

I'm new to Haskell so this could be a stupid question. I'm reading a book where it says `:type sum` is supposed to show `sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a`. Instead of that the message is `sum :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a`. As I've seen in https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Sum this difference is due to -I think- the existence of two different sum functions. Maybe it's something like polymorphism in Java, I'm just starting and I have no idea about how Haskell works.

So my questions are: how could I use the sum function which type is `sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a` instead of the other one? Could you explain me what's going on here?

Comment: The list `sum` is in `Prelude`, i.e. in scope by default, so if you don't do anything special, you will use it. To refer to another `sum`, you need to import `Data.Foldable`. So what is your doubt exactly? If there is some ambiguity, compiler should report about it.

Comment: @laughedelic As of recent GHC releases, the Prelude `sum` is the same one from `Data.Foldable`.

Comment: Since GHC 7.10, several functions in the Prelude have generalized signatures. There is no longer a `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a` - the new `sum :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a` still works on lists (like the old one) but it now also works on other things ([Sequences](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.8.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) or [Sets](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.8.1/docs/Data-Set.html))

Comment: @duplode Cool! I didn't know about the changes.

Comment: It's easy to get confused by the generality of the new Prelude types. Whenever you see `Foldable t` in the constraints, mentally replace every `t a` with `[a]` to get a simpler case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I've seen in https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Sum this difference is due to -I think- the existence of two different sum functions. Maybe it's something like polymorphism in Java

It is, indeed, polymorphism, though not in this way (see the P.S. at the end of this answer). Note that...

```
sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
```

... is already polymorphic in the type of the numbers being summed, so it would work with, for instance, lists of `Integer` and lists of `Double`. The difference between that and...

```
sum :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a
```

... is that this `sum` is also polymorphic in the type of the *container*:

```
GHCi> -- +t makes GHCi print the types automatically.
GHCi> :set +t
GHCi> sum [1 :: Integer, 2, 3]
6
it :: Integer
GHCi> sum [1 :: Double, 2, 3]
6.0
it :: Double
GHCi> import qualified Data.Set as S
GHCi> :t S.fromList
S.fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> S.Set a
GHCi> sum (S.fromList [1 :: Double, 2, 3])
6.0
it :: Double
```

For a container type to be used with `sum`, it has to have an instance of [the `Foldable` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html), which covers functions that, like `sum`, might be expressed as flattening the container into a list and then folding it in some way.

P.S.: Your book says something different than what you have seen because until quite recently the `sum` function in the Prelude used to have the less general, list-specific type, and your book predates the change. Having two different functions called `sum`, even if one is strictly more general than the other, would lead to a name clash (it was for a similar reason that I imported the `Data.Set` module qualified in the example above -- it is a good idea to do so because it defines a few functions such as `map` that clash with Prelude functions, and qualifying them with, say, `S.map` avoids any issues).